# php get the values from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in php and from that array I want to get some values like

The given array is like this

```
Array
(
    [product_id] => 963
    [variation] => Array
        (
            [start_date] => 8 May, 2015
            [adults_travelers] => 15
            [child_travelers] => 0
            [infant_travelers] => 0
        )

    [quantity] => 1
    [line_total] => 1185
    [line_tax] => 0
    [line_subtotal] => 1185
    [line_subtotal_tax] => 0

    [data] => WC_Product_Simple Object
        (
            [id] => 963
            [post] => WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] => 963
                    [post_author] => 2
                    [post_date] => 2015-03-31 13:23:32
                    [post_date_gmt] => 2015-03-31 13:23:32
                    [menu_order] => 0
                    [post_type] => product
                    [post_mime_type] => 
                    [comment_count] => 0
                    [filter] => raw
                )

            [product_type] => simple
            [dimensions:protected] => 
            [shipping_class:protected] => 
            [shipping_class_id:protected] => 0
            [price] => 60
        )

)

Array
(
    [product_id] => 960
    [variation] => Array
        (
            [start_date] => 28 May, 2015
            [adults_travelers] => 10
            [child_travelers] => 2
            [infant_travelers] => 4
        )

    [quantity] => 1
    [line_total] => 1185
    [line_tax] => 0
    [line_subtotal] => 1185
    [line_subtotal_tax] => 0

    [data] => WC_Product_Simple Object
        (
            [id] => 960
            [post] => WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] => 960
                    [post_author] => 2
                    [post_date] => 2015-03-31 13:23:32
                    [post_date_gmt] => 2015-03-31 13:23:32
                    [menu_order] => 0
                    [post_type] => product
                    [post_mime_type] => 
                    [comment_count] => 0
                    [filter] => raw
                )

            [product_type] => simple
            [dimensions:protected] => 
            [shipping_class:protected] => 
            [shipping_class_id:protected] => 0
            [price] => 60
        )

)

Array
(
    [product_id] => 958
    [variation] => Array
        (
            [start_date] => 22 May, 2015
            [adults_travelers] => 11
            [child_travelers] => 10
            [infant_travelers] => 2
        )

    [quantity] => 4
    [line_total] => 1185
    [line_tax] => 0
    [line_subtotal] => 1185
    [line_subtotal_tax] => 0

    [data] => WC_Product_Simple Object
        (
            [id] => 958
            [post] => WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] => 958
                    [post_author] => 2
                    [post_date] => 2015-03-31 13:23:32
                    [post_date_gmt] => 2015-03-31 13:23:32
                    [menu_order] => 0
                    [post_type] => product
                    [post_mime_type] => 
                    [comment_count] => 0
                    [filter] => raw
                )

            [product_type] => simple
            [dimensions:protected] => 
            [shipping_class:protected] => 
            [shipping_class_id:protected] => 0
            [price] => 60
        )

)
```

I want to get the values like `start_date, adult_travelers, child_travelers, infant_travelers` whose product_id is 963 from this array. So can someone tell me how to get those values where the post_id = 963. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable.

Comment: The example you have given is just one of the many elements of another array?

Comment: a simple foreach should suffice, acess array indices as `['index here']` and the objects as `->properties_here`

Comment: Just loop through array and check if `post_id=963`

Comment: @Ghost  can you share some codes?

Comment: @Justinas can you share some code?

Comment: If you need to access a few of the records then, for better performance, move the product ID to the parent array index. Then you can access your data array like: parent[$product_id] without looping.

Comment: This looks like some sort of purchase..? Would it be possible that the same value of 'product_id' can appear more than once in the array? Like same `product_id` but with another `variation` (e.g. some other start date)?

Comment: Just one more thing, do you want the values from the array where `product_id = 963` and/or `post_id = 963`. The last sentences of your question is little bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$product_id = 963;
foreach ($prodArr AS $eachArr) {
    if ($eachArr['product_id'] == $product_id) {
        $start_date = $eachArr['variation']['start_date'];
        $adult_travelers = $eachArr['variation']['adults_travelers'];
        $child_travelers = $eachArr['variation']['child_travelers'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple foreach can do the job correctly as say Ghost :

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($data AS $array) {

    if($array['data']->post->ID == '963') {

        echo $array['variation']['start_date'];
        echo $array['variation']['adults_travelers'];
        echo $array['variation']['child_travelers'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a little bit more detail to what the code does.